# How to set welcome file in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I need to add index.html file as welcome page but the problem is I don't want to add some prefix for appServlet. This is my web.xml file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I placed index.html file in webbfolder of my project. I believe problem is appServlet mapped to /* and that's why I when I try to reach myDomain/index.html or myDomain/ I get 404 error.

Comment: What do you mean "you can't"? What exactly happens when you try?

Comment: @Nikem nothing, I used wrong word I not aloud to do that.

Comment: And? What is not working? What is your exact problem?